# git diff displaying only changed lines in renamed files

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm reviewing a big refactor which moved plenty of files around and changing some of the moved files.

When I use

```
git diff --summary -M master feature/x
```

I can see many files that have 'similarity percentage' above 95% and when I use git difftool it shows that many of files don't actually have any changes.

When I use

```
git diff --unified -M master feature/x
```

it displays the whole contents of renamed files, as removed and then added.

How can I make git diff show me only changed lines in files that it detected as renames?

BTW. What exactly it the percentage number that git displays with --summary?
Why is it 97% when the files look the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
git diff --unified -M master feature/x --color-words
```

It should highlight the words that were changed and not the whole file

[image]

---

You are using the `-M` which is used to display renamed files in the diff.

> **-M[<n>]
>   --find-renames[=<n>]**
>
> Detect renames. If `n` is specified, it is a threshold on the similarity index (i.e. amount of addition/deletions
>   compared to the file's size). For example, `-M90%` means Git should
>   consider a delete/add pair to be a rename if more than 90% of the file
>   hasn't changed. Without a `%` sign, the number is to be read as a
>   fraction, with a decimal point before it. I.e., `-M5` becomes 0.5, and
>   is thus the same as `-M50%`. Similarly, `-M05` is the same as `-M5%`. To
>   limit detection to exact renames, use `-M100%`. The default similarity
>   index is 50%.
>
> Why is it 97% when the files look the same?
>   Have you checked that your white space configuration ignore white space diffs?

Sounds like there is a difference in that (white spaces)